# How to refresh a recyclerview adapter to show the pool thread progress

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, runnable

I have a list of process into a pool of threads, I show the progress of the process in every item of the recycler view, and I need to refresh the adapter in order to show the new process processing in the queue but the only way I can do that is going to another view and coming back.

How can I refresh the adapter to see Live how a process ends and another starts without the need of going to another view and come back to the adapter view.

This is my inner thread  into my recyclerview adapter class, who works updating the progressbar.

```
if (GetSet.getListProcesoCierre().size() > 0 ) {
            String codigoOdtAsigSubida=GetSet.getListProcesoCierre().get(0).getCODIGOASIGNACIONEMG();
            String codigooDTASIG=obEmgOdtAsignacion.getCODIGOASIGNACIONEMG();
           if(codigoOdtAsigSubida.equals(codigooDTASIG)){
               holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               Handler handler = new Handler();
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   int progreso = 0;
                   String fase = "";
                   public void run() {
                     try{
                         progreso = GetSet.getListProcesoCierre().get(0).conexionService.getPorcentageProgreso();
                         fase = GetSet.getListProcesoCierre().get(0).conexionService.getFase();
                     }catch (Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                       holder.progressBar.setProgress(progreso);
                       holder.envioDatosmensaje.setText("" + progreso + "% - " + fase);
                       if (progreso <100) {
                           handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                       }else {
                           holder.txt_odt_estado.setText("CERRADO COMPLETAMENTE");
                           holder.txt_odt_estado.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2ECC71"));
                           holder.btn_cerrar_subir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           holder.ic_reporte_guardado.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           GetSet.setListProcesoCierre(new ArrayList<>());
                           Boolean envioSegundoPlano = SplashScreen.sharedPref2.getBoolean("EnvioSegundoPlano", false);
                           // función a ejecutar
                           if (envioSegundoPlano && GetSet.getListProcesoCierre().size()==0) {
                               Funciones funciones = new Funciones(ctx);
                               funciones.verificarOdtsEnvio();// here I call for the next process in the queue
                              // notify();
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }, 1000);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

Whenever you want to update the `RecyclerView`:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() ->
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
);
```